# What is the teleporter and how does it work?

Tags: spelunky-hd

In the XBox 360 version of Spelunky what is the teleporter and how does it work?

Comment: Reason for downvote?

Comment: These Spelunky questions + answers are so poor...It's like 'What is a door and how does it work?' (I didn't downvote)

Comment: It is also generally frowned upon to ask questions and then answer them in the same 10 minutes for upvotes. (Also didn't downvote)

Comment: @Emerica. - Why? They actually ask you to do it on the stackoverflow blog and give you a handy feature to do it: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/05/encyclopedia-stack-exchange/

Comment: @danRhul - on this one I killed myself the first few times I tried to use the teleporter. It took me a while to figure out how to use it.

Comment: I think the real reason this question got so many downvotes is because it's a question that has a very easy to look up answer.  I can tell you right now that a simple google search for "Spleunky Teleporter" will answer this question for you.  Questions that can be answered from a commond atabase are frowned upon.

Comment: @Zibbobz, I just did a Google search and this question was the third link. This IS a common DB. Both links above it are wikis that (back when I asked this 15 months ago or so) hadn't been updated with any details from the XBox 360 version, just the original PC one. You're wrong by the way _"Questions that can be answered from a common database are frowned upon"_ is entirely incorrect. The goal of all the stackexchange sites was always to become the primary Q&A resource for their area of focus. On the other hand, going "look it up on Google noob!" is frowned upon and generally unhelpful.

Comment: I do apologize. Didn't realize it was like that when the question was asked.  And also I realize that discouraging asking questions that seem obvious is bad.  Sorry.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The teleport is a little blue box with an antenna that you can buy from shops or sometimes dig out of the ground.

It's an item that you have to carry, it can't be thrown but it can be dropped.

Press X when carrying it to teleport 8 squares in the direction that you're facing. What happens depends on the destination:

- An empty square will be teleported to.
- An enemy (including shopkeepers) will be telefragged :-D
- A dig-able square with space directly above or below will result in you appearing above or below it.
- The solid walls around the level will result in instant death.

Once used to it it can help you travel round levels very quickly, but it can also result in your death very quickly.

Comment: I can definitely attest to the fact walls are deadly when using the teleporter.... >.< Every teleporter I have gotten has ended this way.